# iPad - Autoresizing for UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, autoresizingmask

My Code is Here :

```
CGRect mainFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

_contentView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, mainFrame.size.width, mainFrame.size.height-20)] autorelease];
_contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
_contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:_contentView];


self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:_contentView.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[_contentView addSubview:_tableView];
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

I add a tableview on _contentView and _contentView on self.view
on iPhone works good without problem, but on iPad I don't know why when I set autoresizing mask for table view, it increases width and height... without autoresizing mask works good, but I need autoresizing mask for landscape. How to solve this ?

with autoresizing mask
[image: with autoresizing mask]
without autoresizing mask
[image: without autoresizing mask]

Comment: How about catching orientation event and modifying your autoresizing mask?

Comment: I want to work just autoresizing mask

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
_contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES ;
```

Hope this will work.